# Intercept BIG application execution after DLL injection

Tags: debugging, dll, reverse-engineering, disassembly, interception

I must intercept execution in very big application in many places.

**What programs I can use to do this? What techniques exists for this problems?**

Manually reverse engineering and adding hooks is maybe not optimal solution for this problem, because application is very big and some part of application can be updated in some time, i think **with some tools or good practices for this problem i can do this faster**, anyone know how to do?

Anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have access to the code? Also how do you determine what to intercept - some special APIs or patterns?

Comment: @Fasial Ferox: I don't have acces, "how do you determine what to intercept ?" - i dissasembling application with IDA but this application is very big and hard to reverse, i have very big piece of work before me and i searching faster solution, maybe some best-pracices on this problem, some simple tip can speed up my work of approx month/s. I hooking internal functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seeing as the tools part has been covered, here is something for the techniques.

Depending what it is you need to hook and whether or not there is protection invloved, there are a few methods:

1. Relative call/jmp patching in the virtualized binary: this is the simplest, but also a lot of work if you can't automatically find all references to a function, this probably won't work in this cause due to your criteria.
2. IAT/EAT hooking: this is use for imports(IAT) and exports(EAT), great if your targeting a known importted/exported set of API functions. a good example of this can be found [here](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/IAT_Hooking.html) or [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/misc/article.php/c5667)
3. Hot-Patching: Windows XP SP2 introduced something called "hot-patching" (used for realtime system function updates), where all its (the WinAPI) functions start with a 'mov edi,edi', allowing a relative jump to be patched into the free space created above every hot-patchable function([one can do it too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173507(VS.80).aspx)). this is generally used for programs that checksum there IAT's or have other funny forms of protection, more info can be found [here](http://smartz993.wordpress.com/2008/12/07/hot-patching-hook-hopping/) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/0xF9EB_Hooking.aspx)
4. Code-Caving: capturing execution flow by placing redirections in arbitrary code space. see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/codecave.aspx), [here](http://forum.gamedeception.net/threads/13541-Simple-Code-Caving) or [here](http://www.edgeofnowhere.cc/viewtopic.php?t=308049&start=0)
5. VFT/COM Redirection: basically overwriting entries in a objects virtual function table, useful for OOP/COM based applications. see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Hooking_DirectX_COM.aspx)

There are a lot of 3rd party libraries, most famous would probably be [MS Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), one can also look at [APIHijack](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/dll/hooking/article.php/c127/) or a [mini-hook engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/mini_hook_engine.aspx).

Ofcourse nothing can substitute for the initial poking you'll need to do with a debugger like [ollydbg](http://www.ollydgb.de), but knowing the method your gonna use can drastically short them amount time time spent poking around

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  Downvoting and not leaving a reason why is quite rude...

Answer (score 1):

Some details on what exactly you need to do (e.g. how do you determine where to break) would be nice. Depending on your situation, something like [Pin](http://www.pintool.org/) might work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Deviare API Hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/). It's the easiest way you can do what you need. It has some COM objects that you can use to hook an application from a different process. In your process you get full parameter information and you can use it in any programming language (I'm using C# and it works like a charm).
If you need to intercept registry API I suggest using Deviare to debug what you need to intercept but then you will have to make your own hooks, otherwise, you'll find performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do API Hooking if you are interested in intercepting method calls.

Or use some disassembler like softice or [ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) or [win32dasm](http://www.angelfire.com/dc/vashala/hacks%20pages/hack_programs/Win32dasm.html).

Comment: I using IDA Debugger, but analyzing part of big application to find good functions to hook takes may time and i must hook approx 200 functions in 20 executable files (this is totaly diffrent) i searching for solution for speed up my work.